# Run Python script as a Windows service on a non-Python PC

Tags: python, windows, service

I am looking to run my new Python script as a service. The problem is the users most definitely would not have Python installed. After doing research I found the two main options: nssm and the win32serviceutil code, but as far as I understand both require a Python installation on the PC, since you have to specify the path to your python.exe.

Is there any other way to make a Python script to run as soon as Windows is started and run in the background, which doesn't require an existing Python installation?

Comment: Are you looking to compile it first? If so you could use something like [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html) then you don't need python installed

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! I have already compiled it into an .exe exactly using Pyinstaller :) But I was asked if I can make it run as a service. Actually I guess you can make the .exe itself be a service, once it is compiled? (sorry all this is very new to me..)

Comment: I started looking up how to make any .exe run as a service, thanks for the pointer @PigeonBread !